# How to make pagination with Node, Mongoose, Bootstrap and pass it to html?

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongoose, pagination, ejs

I'm building a blog with NodeJS, I'm using "Mongoose Paginate" to divide the database in pages, Bootstrap 4, EJS as view engine and the [JQuery Pagination Plugin](https://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/). I don't know how to actually pass the pagination to the html, I struggled a week but I couldn't find a solution; I want the graphical numbers 1,2,3,4,5 in html to be linked dynamically to the corresponding page, number 1 to www.site/page/1 and so on and at the same time display for example only five clickable numbers at the time, but the numbers should graphically increase as the user clicks on higher numbers. Thank you in advance.

**APP.JS**

```js
app.get('/page/:page', (req, res) => {
 var pagina = req.params.page;
 Blog.paginate({}, {page: pagina, limit: 5}).then((docs) => {
 //console.log(docs)
 res.render('page.ejs', docs)
}, (e) => {
res.status(404)
 });
});
```

**Script.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#pagination-demo').twbsPagination({
    totalPages: 10,
    visiblePages: 5,
    href: true,
    onPageClick: function (event, page) {
      $('#page-content').text('Page ' + page);
    } 
 });
});
```

**Page.ejs**

```html
<nav aria-label="...">
   <ul id="pagination-demo"  class="pagination">
     <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a</li>
     <% for(var i = 1; i <= pages ; i++) {%>
      <li class="page-item"><a href="/page/<%=i%>"><%=i%></a></li>
     <% } %>
     <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you add a question about what you are asking?

Comment: Also, is there a page number anywhere in the HREF (URL)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the ES6 pseudo-code:

```
$(".page-link").click(() => {
  let currentPage = +(location.pathname.replace(/\/page\/(\d+)\b/, "$1")),
      lastPage = currentPage - 1,
      nextPage = currentPage + 1,
      visible = 5,
      max = 10;

      // the rest of the code goes here
});
```